Primefaces fileUpload not working if page is served by OcpSoft rewrite
I'm developing a Jakarta EE 10 web app with:
- JDK Temurin 17.0.12+7 
- PrimeFaces 14.0.8
- OcpSoft Rewrite 10.0.2.Final
- Payara 6 2024.11

I've a JSF page with a fileUpload component that uploads a file.
When I navigate the page:
http://localhost:8080/app/test.xhtml
fileUpload works like a charm.
As I map a different url on that page using OcpSoft Rewrite ex.
http://localhost:8080/app/test1
the page is diplayed but fileUpload components doesn't work anymore neither on /test.xhtml nor in /test1 (no growl messages is printed, in debug mode setter is not called) and I don't understand why.
The networking browser tab shows a correct ajax response (200 OK), and the response is:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response>
<changes>
<update>
 ... resources list css/js and so on...
</update>
<update id="j_id1:jakarta.faces.ViewState:0">
<![CDATA[4643052824996170439:-5027703796391201549]]>
</update>
</changes>
</partial-response>

Here the relevant parts:
test.xhtml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:h="jakarta.faces.html"
      xmlns:f="jakarta.faces.core" 
      xmlns:p="primefaces">
  <f:view>  
    <h:head>
      <h:outputStylesheet name="css/prism/prism.css" />
      <h:outputStylesheet name="css/primeicons/primeicons.css" />
      <h:outputStylesheet name="css/primeflex/primeflex3.css" />
      <h:outputStylesheet name="css/primeflex/extensions.css" />
      <h:outputStylesheet name="css/primeflex/themes/saga.css" />
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
      <h:form id="form">
        <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />
        <p:fileUpload id="attachment" 
                      value="#{testController.attachment}"
                      mode="simple" 
                      skinSimple="true" 
                      auto="true"
                      process="@this"
                      update="form:messages"
                      listener="#{testController.handleFileUpload}"
                      label="Add attachment">
          <p:validateFile allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(pdf)$/" sizeLimit="100000000" />
        </p:fileUpload>
        <p:message for="attachment"/>
      </h:form>
    </h:body>
  </f:view>
</html>

TestController.java
package test.controllers;

import jakarta.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import jakarta.faces.context.FacesContext;
import jakarta.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import jakarta.inject.Named;
import java.io.Serializable;
import org.primefaces.event.FileUploadEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.file.UploadedFile;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class TestController implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  
  private UploadedFile attachment;

  public UploadedFile getAttachment() {
    return attachment;
  }

  public void setAttachment(UploadedFile attachment) {
    System.out.println("Here I am...");
    this.attachment = attachment;
  }

  public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Ok", "File " + event.getFile().getFileName() + " successfully uploaded.");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
  }

  public void initSomeData() {
    // do nothing ATM
  }
}

Until now all is ok, I call /test.xhtml and file upload works...
Now I insert the rewrite:
package test.providers;

import jakarta.faces.event.PhaseId;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletContext;
import org.ocpsoft.rewrite.annotation.RewriteConfiguration;
import org.ocpsoft.rewrite.config.Configuration;
import org.ocpsoft.rewrite.config.ConfigurationBuilder;
import org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.config.HttpConfigurationProvider;
import org.ocpsoft.rewrite.config.Invoke;
import org.ocpsoft.rewrite.el.El;
import org.ocpsoft.rewrite.faces.config.PhaseOperation;
import org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.config.rule.Join;

@RewriteConfiguration
public class RewriteConfigurationProvider extends HttpConfigurationProvider {

  @Override
  public int priority() {
    return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public Configuration getConfiguration(final ServletContext context) {
    return ConfigurationBuilder.begin()
            .addRule(
                    Join.path("/test1").to("/test.xhtml")
            ).perform(PhaseOperation.enqueue(Invoke.binding(El.retrievalMethod("testController.initSomeData"))).after(PhaseId.RESTORE_VIEW)
            );

  }
}

pom.xml
...
   
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>10.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
      <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
      <version>14.0.8</version>
      <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
      <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
      <artifactId>rewrite-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>10.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
      <artifactId>rewrite-integration-faces</artifactId>
      <version>10.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.ppodgorsek.email</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-email-jakarta</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
      <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
      <version>10.22.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
      <artifactId>flyway-mysql</artifactId>
      <version>10.22.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
      <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
      <version>14.0.8</version>
      <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.17.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
      <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
      <version>4.6</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

Now, calling /test.xhtml or /test1, fileUpload doesn't work anymore.
Can I have some tips to bypass this issue ?
Thanks in advance

Step 1: check the developer console of the browser and especially the networking tab. Pretty sure ajax requests will be failing and the error may give a clue as to why.

@Gimby already done, no errors in the networking tab, response status 200 (OK), the response is diplayed as: 
<update ...resources...>4643052824996170439:-5027703796391201549

Yet that information is not in the question.

@Gimby: Question updated... Thanks...
